# how to view selected area source in from UIWebview in iphone SDK?

Tags: iphone, ios4

iPhone SDK:

Like web-browser does, user select any text area then press right click then select view source. browser will show you selected area source.

Now I want to achieve same functionality in `UIWebview` ? User open webpage in in-app browser (in `UIWebview`), user select any text area, i want to get selected text area source, how this can be done in ios sdk ?